# Javascript test for window.location.assign not working

Tags: javascript, testing

I am trying to test code that redirects to an external url. A manual test shows that the redirect happens, but the test doesn't recognize that 'window.location.assign' has been called. The code looks like this:

```
function redirectUser(foo) {
  if (foo.active) {
    window.location.assign("http://newUrl.com");
  }
```

And here's the test:

```
it('redirects to newUrl when active', () => {
  redirectUser({"active": true});
  const mock = jest.fn(window.location.assign);
  expect(mock).toBeCalled();
});
```

When I run it, however, the test fails with this message:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called.
```

I've tried adding another toy function just above window.location.assign and tested that, and it does get called, test passes. Does window.location need some special treatment? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `expect(jest.fn(window.location.assign)).toBeCalled()`? This might be a problem with `assign` using a `this` reference internally.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Yes, same result.